# Move the "required" span outside the field label

Tags: theming, entities

When a field is required, an asterisk is added inside the `<label>` tag in a `<span>` tag. for some reasons, I need to move the `<span>` tag outside the `<label>` tag, beside the `<label>` tag.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this goal via implementing [theme_form_element_label](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/theme_form_element_label/7).

I hope you already know how to implement or override theme.

e.g.

```
function MYTHEMENAME_form_element_label($variables) {
  $element = $variables ['element'];
  // This is also used in the installer, pre-database setup.
  $t = get_t();

  // If title and required marker are both empty, output no label.
  if ((!isset($element ['#title']) || $element ['#title'] === '') && empty($element ['#required'])) {
    return '';
  }

  // If the element is required, a required marker is appended to the label.
  $required = !empty($element ['#required']) ? theme('form_required_marker', array('element' => $element)) : '';

  $title = filter_xss_admin($element ['#title']);

  $attributes = array();
  // Style the label as class option to display inline with the element.
  if ($element ['#title_display'] == 'after') {
    $attributes ['class'] = 'option';
  }
  // Show label only to screen readers to avoid disruption in visual flows.
  elseif ($element ['#title_display'] == 'invisible') {
    $attributes ['class'] = 'element-invisible';
  }

  if (!empty($element ['#id'])) {
    $attributes ['for'] = $element ['#id'];
  }

  // The leading whitespace helps visually separate fields from inline labels.
  return ' <label' . drupal_attributes($attributes) . '>' . $t('!title', array('!title' => $title,)) . "</label>" . $t('!required', array('!required' => $required)) . "\n";
}
```

Put this function on template.php

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how to achieve that, I know that I have to use such override but don't have enough knowledge in php

Comment: If you know the full answer Ruspesh, do you mind to help him out, I actually would like to know the answer as well.

Comment: What HTML structure you want to achieve ?